# What's the story behind this photo from WWI?

Tags: world-war-one, battle, death, photography, combat

### Warning:  the photograph below is very graphic and may disturb some viewers, hence the spoiler tag.  Click at your own risk.

> [image]

The picture shows the  skeletal corpse of a dead German infantryman (the helmet is clearly German) outside a dugout shelter. It has become fairly famous, and is featured in the opening credits of the classic BBC documentary series *The Great War*.

The fact that the body was left in situ long enough for the flesh to decay completely suggests to me that it may be from one of the most lengthy engagements on the Western Front - perhaps  the Somme Campaign or the Battle of Verdun, either late in the battle or shortly after it ended, but this is just an informed guess.

Do we know who this man was, where and when the picture was taken, or anything else about it?

Comment: Initial searches are finding this linked with Somme...

Comment: Have you asked *The Great War*?

Comment: @Schwern - It was made in 1964, so I doubt the writers, production team, etc, are still around.

Comment: @WadCheber Oh! Thought you meant the current YouTube documentary series. Might be worth an email to BBC archives, and to the YT series.

Comment: One thing to consider -- he's not completely "skeletal". His hands -- which I suspect are in gloves -- appear fairly intact, and the rest of the uniform appears to be fairly well filled-out. Which leads me to believe the skull was "cleaned" by rats or other scavengers as it's the only exposed portion of the body. This could happen quite quickly, so it's hard to say how long the body may have been left in-place.

Answer (score 2):

This image seems to source from the Beaumont Hamel region, sometime during (or after) the [Battle of Somme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Somme).

> Beaumont-Hamel was situated near the northern end of the 45-kilometre
>   front being assaulted by the joint French and British force.

Heavy losses from one Newfoundland regiment caused the founding of a memorial:

- [Beaumont-Hamel Newfoundland Memorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaumont-Hamel_Newfoundland_Memorial)

Versions of the image can be found on both

- [Alamy](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/beaumont-hamel.html?blackwhite=1)
- [Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.com/photos/beaumont-hamel?excludenudity=true&sort=mostpopular&mediatype=photography&phrase=beaumont%20hamel)

All I find concerning the soldier has him as unidentified German soldier.